# Express VIs in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

Some days ago, I started getting experience with the so-called Express VIs in LabVIEW (8.6).

It has turned out that I should put them into `%somewhere%/user.lib/_express`, i. e. outside the project directory.

If I do so, they are of use for me and only for me. As soon as someone else tries to work with this project, e.g. if it is in a source control repository or something else, he cannot do so because he hasn't my Express VI templates.

Is there a way to define an Express VI when it does not com from the menu, but lies in the project directory?

Comment: what happens if you don't save it in user.lib/_express?

Comment: it doesn't show up in the palettes, and stays unusable...

Comment: can you add the containing folder to the palette? Tools>Advanced>Change visible palettes

Comment: that would be an option - thank you! Then I have to fool around with the palette editor, but as it is a one-time action, it won't hur that much... thank you again!

Comment: really seems to work - except that the Config VI cannot be found at once, but I think that has nothing to do with the menu, but with the express VI itself. So this seems to be the solution. Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save express VIs to any location, just add their containing folder to the palette with `Tools>Advanced>Change visible palettes`.

Comment: thanks, that helped me a lot - as well with understanding the palette stuff as such.

Answer (score 1):

As a point of style, Express VI's are not the way to go, as they hide quite a bit of the functionality. You're usually going to be better off using a Functional Global structure, or its generalization: the Action Engine.

Comment: I don't understand this comment. An Express VI is a subVI whose options can be configured via a dialog. A functional global or an action engine is a VI that stores persistent data between calls and may take different actions on that data based on its inputs at runtime. An express VI could also be a functional global or action engine, but it doesn't have to be. Also, once configured you can open the Express VI as a standard subVI and see all its functionality.

Comment: What I mean here is that the exact actions a particular instance of an Express VI will perform is not clear by a simple glance at the block diagram, whereas with an action engine, you typically use a strict typedef enum to control which action occurs, and wire that into the action engine. (Naturally, I'm assuming here that your enum has descriptive options!) Thus, action engine code tells you more about what is going to happen than with the Express VI approach. See Peter Blume's book *The LabVIEW Style Book* for reference.

Comment: I still think that's a problem of any VI with persistent data though, not just of Express VIs (which don't necessarily have persistent data, do they?). I agree that the functional global and action engine are good design patterns that all LabVIEW coders should know.